# Cloud code aftersave method not working

Tags: parse-platform

I just need help to trigger my aftersave method in cloud code. I am new to parse.
The following are the steps I followed

1) I save one class named "Send" in my android code using send.save()

2) I have set up a cloud directory in my windows by following
     https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/unix

3) I have created a method like this in main.js

```
 Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Send", function(request) {
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query("User");

    userQuery.get(request.object.get("name"), {

    success: function(user) {
          Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

                console.log("success");
                alert("success"); 

            },
            error : function(error) {
               console.log("error" + error);
            }
    });
  });
```

4)I have deployed my cloud code using parse deploy

5) When I save the send object it gets saved to the Parse DB. But the aftersave function not getting called or I cannot see anything happening. Can anyone guide me whats missing?

Help is much appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set master key inside success callback, i don't think it has any meaning to it. Try setting it before:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Send", function(request) {
   Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();    
   var userQuery = new Parse.Query("User");

   userQuery.get(request.object.get("name"), {

      success: function(user) {

         console.log("success");
         alert("success"); 

        },
        error : function(error) {
           console.log("error" + error);
        }
   });
});
```

Also, please note that in your Parse.com "Core" interface, you have a button on the left named "Logs", when you enter this one, you get detailed log of all your cloud code activity. When you look there you can easily track your success or errors.